# Will termination resistors help with USB data line "dead legs"?

Tags: resistors, usb, interference, termination, reflection

I'm designing a USB switch, using small relays to connect a USB peripheral to any one of ten PCs.

The USB traces from the peripheral branch out to ten different relays. I anticipate these "dead legs" might cause reflections or interference on the USB signal lines.

I have two ideas for solving this.

1. Place 1MΩ resistors to ground on each dead leg, at each relay, such that they will be switched into play when the relay is not active. Thus, all inactive relays will terminate their own dead legs to ground.
2. Arrange the relays in a line, and place 1MΩ resistors to ground on the data lines at the end of the line. One set of termination resistors for the whole set.

The switch is intended for use with low-speed peripherals like mice and keyboards; but still, I'd rather avoid the possibility of issues.

Am I worried needlessly? Are either of these solutions viable? Or is there something else I can do?

Answer (score 3):

Using a termination of 1 Mohm is useless. Even if you use one at end of line or one at each relay. The impedance of USB is 90 ohms differential, or, approximately 45 ohms single-ended.

Relays are the wrong component anyway for switching a supposedly 12 Mbps signal, assuming no device used 480 Mbps for any purpose.

Use a switching IC meant for switching USB. The final issue is, how to power the switched devices properly. You can't leave the devices powered if the PC that is currently connected is turned off.

Comment: Why are relays not suitable for switching USB? I'm not using them to communicate. Just to switch a peripheral from one PC to another.

Comment: I have already solved the power issue – devices won't be powered unless the PC is on. It is the issue of signal reflections and interference I seek to avoid or solve.

Comment: @SodAlmighty If you are using relays to switch devices between PCs, the devices surely need to communicate through the relays. Are your relays rated for high speed data communication through them?

Comment: @SodAlmighty For further info we do have a question you just asked : https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/581190/why-cant-i-route-usb-lines-through-a-relay

Comment: There *are* relays suitable for switching high-frequency signals. They're just probably not the best choice for this purpose.

Comment: An IC intended for switching multiple USB channels would be far more cheaper and practical than even a single HF relay capable of switching USB.

Comment: @SodAlmighty [MAX4999 USB 2.0 Hi-Speed Differential 8:1 Multiplexer](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/MAX4999.pdf) has _Figure 5. Combining Two MAX4999 Devices for 16:1 USB Connections_ might suit your requirement for muxing USB peripherals to one of ten PCs, and designed for data rates up to 480Mbps. Just the first USB mux I found from a search. Haven't checked for layout guidance, to address your question about signal reflections.

Comment: Hm. I didn't realise that relays would be unable to pass USB signals. I guess I will need to look into USB mux ICs. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't understand. If the devices never enumerate above Full Speed, even power relays are simply *fine* (wiping current aside). It's just logic-level CMOS stuff, it's nothing special. 480Mbps isn't extraordinary either, but will require compact signal relays, preferably rated for high frequencies (but proper RF types will not be required).

Comment: @TimWilliams Logic level stuff at 12 Mbps. Do you regularly pass 12 MHz data buses through random relays? The bandwidth of a square wave is quite high, at least 5th harmonic or 60 MHz must pass in order to still look like a square wave. But the USB slew rate is limited to fastest minimum of 4ns, that's still a bandwidth of 87.5 MHz, so at least up to 7th harmonic of 12 MHz must pass unaltered. On the other hand, 4ns also means, the wavelength is 1.7 meters (on a PCB), so any structure less than 17cm should not be a problem. Coupling and crosstalk of relays are problems even with audio.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Even the stub length of a power relay is a handful of cm. Crosstalk is small at signal impedances (100s ohms), compared to audio's 10k's, likewise the logic thresholds are much, much wider (e.g. 30%VCC versus 80dB+ audio muting levels). And it's not an EMC concern per se (shielding can be placed over the relays if found necessary, but more likely a regular compact/signal type won't be big enough to matter).

Comment: These are incredibly small relays: http://www.relay-distributor.com/common/db/pdf/signal/HFD4.pdf
Do we think it's feasible? Or should I abandon the idea as a lost cause?

Comment: And if it *is* feasible.....that brings us back to the question of dead legs and proper termination of same.